# Problems access and installing PIL

Tags: python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I have used the PIL library for image manipulation for over 2 years without any mishaps. Suddenly a few days ago it started acting up on me. So I followed advice from this forum by uninstalling PIL and trying to reinstall it only to met with a message that no matching distribution was found for PIL.

[image: Error message]

Please Help!!

Comment: So... why not try to install `Pillow` or, if it doesn't work, search the web for installation tutorials for PIL?

Comment: You want to install Pillow, not PIL.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pillow
```

You uninstalled Pillow successfully, so install it again like this.